# Xamarin IOS App Crash In Store and works in TestFlight

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

As the title states, my application works great in TestFlight for all of the users, however when I submit to the store it crashes on startup. I have the crash logs and will post them below but I am running out of ideas on what the deal is with this. Any ideas would be appreciated. The app also works fine in debug mode on my simulator or IPhone.

```
Thread 0 name:  tid_303  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000185a9d348 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000185bb1354 pthread_kill$VARIANT$mp + 396
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000185a0cfd8 abort + 140
3   AppWinbid.iOS                   0x00000001016930c0 mono_handle_native_crash + 16134336 (mini-exceptions.c:2548)
4   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x0000000185babb60 _sigtramp + 52
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000185bb1354 pthread_kill$VARIANT$mp + 396
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000185a0cfd8 abort + 140
7   AppWinbid.iOS                   0x0000000101792488 xamarin_printf + 17179784 (runtime.m:2218)
8   AppWinbid.iOS                   0x00000001016cf1d8 mono_invoke_unhandled_exception_hook + 16380376 (exception.c:1084)
9   AppWinbid.iOS                   0x0000000101692d18 mono_handle_exception_internal + 16133400 (mini-exceptions.c:1886)
10  AppWinbid.iOS                   0x0000000101691d50 mono_handle_exception + 16129360 (mini-exceptions.c:2117)
11  AppWinbid.iOS                   0x000000010168a6d8 mono_arm_throw_exception + 16099032 (exceptions-arm64.c:411)
12  AppWinbid.iOS                   0x0000000100a03878 throw_exception + 168
13  AppWinbid.iOS                   0x00000001008fe35c System_Runtime_ExceptionServices_ExceptionDispatchInfo_Throw + 44
14  AppWinbid.iOS                   0x0000000100900da4 System_Runtime_CompilerServices_AsyncMethodBuilderCore__c__ThrowAsyncb__6_0_object + 84
15  AppWinbid.iOS                   0x0000000100a99968 UIKit_UIKitSynchronizationContext__Postc__AnonStorey0__m__0 + 3578216 (UIKitSynchronizationContext.cs:24)
16  AppWinbid.iOS                   0x0000000100a73e04 Foundation_NSAsyncActionDispatcher_Apply + 3423748 (NSAction.cs:163)
17  AppWinbid.iOS                   0x00000001009d3744 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 244
18  AppWinbid.iOS                   0x00000001016a038c mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 16188300 (mini-runtime.c:2526)
19  AppWinbid.iOS                   0x0000000101705544 do_runtime_invoke + 16602436 (object.c:2829)
20  AppWinbid.iOS                   0x00000001017054a4 mono_runtime_invoke + 16602276 (object.c:2983)
21  AppWinbid.iOS                   0x00000001007346e8 native_to_managed_trampoline_3(objc_object*, objc_selector*, _MonoMethod**, unsigned int) + 18152 (registrar.m:106)
22  AppWinbid.iOS                   0x0000000100734bec -[__MonoMac_NSAsyncActionDispatcher xamarinApplySelector] + 19436 (registrar.m:6968)
23  Foundation                      0x0000000186973a50 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 340
24  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185f2c358 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
25  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185f2c2d8 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 88
26  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185f2bbb4 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 288
27  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185f29738 __CFRunLoopRun + 1048
28  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185e4a2d8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
29  GraphicsServices                0x0000000187cdbf84 GSEventRunModal + 100
30  UIKit                           0x000000018f3f7880 UIApplicationMain + 208
31  AppWinbid.iOS                   0x0000000100afc470 wrapper_managed_to_native_UIKit_UIApplication_UIApplicationMain_int_string___intptr_intptr + 3982448 (/<unknown>:1)
32  AppWinbid.iOS                   0x0000000100a92e9c UIKit_UIApplication_Main_string___intptr_intptr + 3550876 (UIApplication.cs:79)
33  AppWinbid.iOS                   0x0000000100a92e5c UIKit_UIApplication_Main_string___string_string + 3550812 (UIApplication.cs:63)
34  AppWinbid.iOS                   0x0000000100755174 AppWinbid_iOS_Application_Main_string__ + 151924 (/<unknown>:1)
35  AppWinbid.iOS                   0x00000001009d3744 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 244
36  AppWinbid.iOS                   0x00000001016a038c mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 16188300 (mini-runtime.c:2526)
37  AppWinbid.iOS                   0x0000000101705544 do_runtime_invoke + 16602436 (object.c:2829)
38  AppWinbid.iOS                   0x0000000101707f48 do_exec_main_checked + 16613192 (object.c:4623)
39  AppWinbid.iOS                   0x0000000101689ef0 mono_jit_exec + 16097008 (driver.g.c:1040)
40  AppWinbid.iOS                   0x000000010179648c xamarin_main + 17196172 (monotouch-main.m:0)
41  AppWinbid.iOS                   0x00000001007550c8 main + 151752 (main.m:85)
42  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018596e56c start + 4
```

Comment: `UIKit_UIKitSynchronizationContext__Postc.....` Are you performing any functions in `Application.Main`? Or the related `UIApplicationDelegate.FinishedLaunching` (or `.actor`)

Comment: static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate");
    } 
In the OnStart method of the PCL project I am checking user login and directing to 1 page if not logged in or another if they are.

Comment: Calling any `void async` in that logic?

Comment: No, I do have a few async Task<bool> being called that are calling an HttpClient service.

Comment: Any Keychain / NSUserDefaults calls in the startup logic? Any try/finally  (using) within the HttpClient continuations?

Comment: UILaunchStoryboardName
NSCalendarsUsageDescription
NSCameraUsageDescription
NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription
NSMicrophoneUsageDescription
NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription
NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription
XSAppIconAssets
XSLaunchImageAssets On the launch images, I never specified any images, could that be the issue?

Comment: Scratch that, I did add the launch images, I did notice in my project Info.Plist under the iTunes Artwork that I don't have a 512 X 512 image.